# A page can only have one server tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a master page with me but when i run the shopcart page, it shows me the error "A page can have only one server-side Form tag". i dont know which runat to be removed
Any help would be appreciated thanks :)

this are my codes for master page

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="headersContainer" runat="server" />   

<div id="container">
<div id="header">

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li ><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="examples.html">Orders</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shipment</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
<div id="body">
    <div id="content">
    <div style= "text-align:right";>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1"  runat="server" Text="Items in Shopping Cart" BackColor="#FF531A" 
            BorderStyle="Dotted" CausesValidation="False" ForeColor="White" 
            Font-Bold /></form></div>

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"  >

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>


    </div>
    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>    
           <li>
                <h3>User</h3>
                <ul class="blocklist">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="examples.html">Login</a></li
                </ul>
            </li>
            &nbsp
           <li>
                <h3>Categories</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.themeforest.net/?ref=spykawg" ><strong>Gadgets</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.dreamhost.com/r.cgi?259541" ><strong>Accessories</strong></a> </strong></li>

                </ul>
            </li>
            &nbsp
            <li>
                <h3>Search</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <form method="get" class="searchform" action="http://wpdemo.justfreetemplates.com/" >
                            <p>
                                <input type="text" size="12" value="" name="s" class="s" />
                                <input type="submit" class="searchsubmit formbutton" value="Search" />
                            </p>
                        </form> 
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>



        </ul> 
    </div>
```

this are codes for my shopCart page

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<form id= "form1" runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" >
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="grdCatalogue" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        Width ="100px" onselectedindexchanged="grdCatalogue_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" >
            <ControlStyle Width="80px" />
            <FooterStyle Width="80px" />
            <HeaderStyle Width="80px" />
            <ItemStyle Width="80px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="Sold By" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date Uploaded" />
            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Image1FileName" 
                DataImageUrlFormatString="~/Image/{0}" HeaderText="Image">
            </asp:ImageField>
            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" HeaderText="Add to Cart" 
                ShowSelectButton="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: You have multiple `Form` tag with `runat="server" ` attribute. Use a single `<form runat="server">` in master page and put everything under that form tag

Comment: Have the runat="server" only on the form that contains the main placeholder.

Comment: remove form tag in shopCart page, because the master page have the form tag you don't need it in pages using master page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove  `runat="server"` from `form` tag in your ShopCart 
page.
You can remove your `form` tag too from `shopcart` page as your master page already contains `Form` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `form` tag from your `shopCart page`

In ASP.NET model, single server tag is responsible for all the page processing.

Answer (score 0):

Your shopping cart page has

```
<form id= "form1" runat="server">
```

Which is not required as the contentplaceholder is already within a form. The contents of the contentplaceholder will be added to the master page.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need another form on the shopCart page as you have one on your master page.  The form on your master page is included on every page that uses your master page. so I would remove the following tag from the shopCart page;

```
<form id= "form1" runat="server">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `<form id= "form1" runat="server">` in your child page

because the `ContentPlaceHolder1` is already have form tag in master page !

Answer (score 0):

Update your shopping cart page

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" >
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<br />
<asp:GridView ID="grdCatalogue" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    Width ="100px" onselectedindexchanged="grdCatalogue_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" >
        <ControlStyle Width="80px" />
        <FooterStyle Width="80px" />
        <HeaderStyle Width="80px" />
        <ItemStyle Width="80px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="Sold By" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date Uploaded" />
        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Image1FileName" 
            DataImageUrlFormatString="~/Image/{0}" HeaderText="Image">
        </asp:ImageField>
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" HeaderText="Add to Cart" 
            ShowSelectButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```